# Why renv in docker is not installing and loading packages?

Tags: r, docker, renv

This is the first time I'm using Docker. I have tried a few times but this is the first time where I'm containerizing the project. The project generates reports using `latex` and `officer`. However, after building the container and running the image, Rstudio shows that none of the packages are installed and loaded.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM rocker/verse:4.0.5

ENV RENV_VERSION 0.15.1
RUN R -e "install.packages('remotes', repos = c(CRAN = 'https://cloud.r-project.org'))"
RUN R -e "remotes::install_github('rstudio/renv@${RENV_VERSION}')"

WORKDIR /REAL
COPY . .
RUN apt-get -y update --fix-missing
#RUN apt-get -y install build-essential \
#   libssl-dev \
#   libcurl4-openssl-dev \
#   libxml2-dev \
#   libfontconfig1-dev \
#   libcairo2-dev
RUN R -e 'options(renv.consent = TRUE); renv::restore(lockfile = "/REAL/renv.lock"); renv::activate()'
```

##### Building Docker image

```
docker build -t reports/real .
```

##### Running docker with rstudio support

```
docker run --rm -d -p 8787:8787 --name real_report -e ROOT=TRUE -e DISABLE_AUTH=TRUE -v C:/Users/test/sources/REAL_Reports:/home/rstudio/REAL_Reports reports/real:latest
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it so that all packages that `renv` has discovered are installed and loaded?

Answer (score 2):

> RUN R -e 'options(renv.consent = TRUE); renv::restore(lockfile = "/REAL/renv.lock"); renv::activate()'

You likely need to activate / load your project before calling `restore()`, or just forego using a project-local library altogether.

https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/docker.html may also be useful here.